# Display graph with button click in pyqt and python(x,y) matplotlibwidget

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, qt-designer, pythonxy

I have made a gui with qt designer and use pyqt. I added a matplotlibwidget which is provided with the python(x,y) package. How can I display a graph by clicking a button on the GUI? Thanks!

Comment: You should try to add an example of what you did already, e.g. how you define your data, what kind of plot you want, what should happen, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

```
class MyClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = PYQTMainWindow.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        ...
        self.connect(self.ui.myButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.DisplayGraph)
        #next line will work too:
        #self.ui.myButton.clicked(self.DisplayGraph)

    def DisplayGraph(self):
        #... set your graph here the way you want
```